# how to make executable file from your osx app

Tags: xcode, macos, executable

I have developed OSX app with Xcode. I am trying to make an executable file from my app but I face some problem. The executable file that Xcode gives me is not suitable for older version of Mac. I would appreciate if you help me how can I make the executable file.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a Deployment Target setting in both the Project Info page and the Targets General page of your project file that you can set to the minimum OS version that you want to support.